# How do I return an array from a vba function in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I would like to return an array of unknown size from a vba function. I have little experience with vba.

I googled this question and found this page: [Returning Arrays From VBA User Defined Functions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/returningarraysfromvba.aspx).

It gives the following example for a function that will return an array:

```
Function Test() As Variant
    Dim V() As Variant
    Dim N As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim C As Long
    ReDim V(1 To 3, 1 To 4)
    For R = 1 To 3
        For C = 1 To 4
            N = N + 1
            V(R, C) = N
        Next C
    Next R
    Test = V
End Function
```

So I typed `Alt+F11`, created a new module and entered this function. Then, in my workbook, I created a new sheet, typed `=Test()` in a cell and hit `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`, and a `1` appeared in a single cell.

What am I doing wrong? According to the site, the output of this should be

> an array with 3 rows and 4 columns that contains the integers from 1
>   to 12.

Comment: It did return the array, but if the formula is confirmed for just one cell then that cell will only show the top-left element of the array. Each cell on the worksheet displays only one element of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First hi-light **A1** through **D3**.  Then enter:

```
=Test()
```

as an *array formula*:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.